# Is the Rapier a Superior or Military weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, background

I keep seeing the Gritty Sergeant and Noble Bred for War backgrounds mentioned as ways to gain proficiency with rapier. However rapier is listed in PHB as a superior weapon, and GS/NBfW grant proficiency with a simple or military weapon, so how can they be used to gain rapier proficiency?

If rapier is in fact a military weapon, where is that listed?

Comment: I know this is irrelevant to DND, but I'd just like to point out that, IRL, the [rapier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapier) most certainly was _not_ a military weapon. A typical rapier would feature a long and slender blade with a fancy guard, designed for dueling, self-defense and looking impressive at social events. If you took one to a battlefield, you'd be laughed at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DDI lists [Rapier](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3565) as a Military weapon:

> Rapier
>
> Military one-handed melee weapon
>
> Cost: 25
>
> Damage: 1d8

And asserts that it can be found in:

> Published in Player's Handbook, page(s) 218, Heroes of the Fallen Lands, page(s) 331, Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms, page(s) 334, Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium, page(s) 21.

Check the later books, or the [errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdatePH.pdf), page 21 that asserts:

> Rapier
>
> Page 218: The weapon is longer a superior military
> weapon.

Comment: Ah, I don't have DDI and only have access to PHB (out of the books you named), where it's listed as a Superior weapon. I'd wondered if there was errata for that, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: "The weapon is longer a superior military weapon."

Thank you WotC, for muddying things up with poor grammar. :-P

Answer (score 1):

The PHB lists Rapier as a Superior Melee weapon. [According to the DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=item&id=3565), it was later rereleased as a Military weapon, probably by Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium.

The Gritty Sergeant<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/background.aspx?id=49)</sup> is compatible with this latest update, but not the original rapier:

> Benefit: You gain proficiency in a simple or military weapon of your choice, and you gain a +1 bonus to initiative checks.